# VBA Find function not picking up the correct value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use the find function in VBA, but it's giving me an issue. If the value that I'm searching for is 3, it will pick up other cells that have 3's in them like 33 or 333.

How do I get the function to find an exact match?

Thanks

Here's the malfunctioning function:

```
Set v = rng.Find(NextItem)
```

Answer (score 2):

Tell it to look for complete matches:

```
set v = rng.Find("3", lookat:=xlWhole)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can actually set the function like on the user interface to find an exact match with

```
LookAt:=xlWhole
```

Then you just modify your function to:

> Set v = rng.Find(what:=NextItem, LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)

I hope this works, I can't try it right now, but this is probably the right way!